# AS3 Project - How do I import TLF?

Tags: actionscript-3, text, import, air, flashdevelop

Using Flash develop I need to create a `TLFTextField` in an AIR AS3 project, but where do I find the swc to import?

I have imported textLayout.swc from the the flex sdk, but I get the error:

```
Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: TLFTextField.
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing any code. Do you have the proper import statements in your class?

Comment: Nope I definitely don't have the correct import statements as TLFTextField is not part of textLayout.swc, so I think I must need to add another SWC to the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLFTextField is bundled in tlfruntime.swc. As far as I know, that's only bundled with Flash, not the Flex SDK.

Comment: Yeah that's the only place I could find the TLFTextField Class, Looking at the AS3 examples for the Text layout Framework - I can see they don't use TLFTextField, instead a variety confusing sounding different classes!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the source code:
http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/sandbox/viatropos/trunk/frameworks/projects/spark/src/mx/core/TLFTextField.as